# Clever use of SUBSTRING on Codewars, can someone plesae explain to me how this works? - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

Please assist me in explaining how the coder created this great solution, I'll briefly explain the table:

```
select * from people
```

returns the value:

```
name
Anibal Dorothea Tromp IV
```

The challenge is solved in many ways, but one solution really amazed me:

```
select
  substring(name, '^(.+)\s\S+\s\S+$') as name,
  substring(name, '^.+\s(\S+)\s\S+$') as first_lastname,
  substring(name, '^.+\s(\S+)$') as second_lastname
from people
```

returns the result:

```
name             first_lastname   second_lastname  
Anibal Dorothea  Tromp              IV
```

the real table has many more rows, some with 1 first name, others with 2 first names.  So the challenge was to separate the names with the first name (name) being a different length word and sometimes more than 1 word.

If I look at the documentation on substring, there is no mention of this method, please explain to me how his great solution works or point me in the direction of a site that explains some of the components of this solution.

Many thanks,
Tim

Comment: I am curious how the accepted answer was chosen, did my answer not answer your question more precisely i.e. the regular expression piece.

Comment: @Seany84 apologies, I forgot to tick your answer, have amended now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This special string you are referring to is called a regular expression. Regular expressions are available in many RDBMS and programming languages.

Postgres does have documentation on this here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

The query above, has three substring with regex patterns in them:

1. `'^(.+)\s\S+\s\S+$'` matches every group except the last two. `Anibal Dorothea`
2. `'^.+\s(\S+)\s\S+$'` matches the second last group `Tromp`
3. `'^.+\s(\S+)$'` mathces the final group `IV`

If you changed the input text to `Anibal Dorothea Tromp the IV` the output from the `select` above would be:

```
name                    first_lastname   second_lastname  
Anibal Dorothea Tromp              the                IV
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `substring()` like this -- and it is well documented -- this seems like a good use case for `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(name, ' ', 1),
       split_part(name, ' ', 2),
       split_part(name, ' ', 3),
       split_part(name, ' ', 4)
```

Or if you need a more advanced splitter, you can use `regexp_split_to_array()`.

Comment: yes, this can be combined with a CASE WHEN function as someone used to get a solution

Comment: @Timmay . . . Is there a reason you decided to unaccept this answer?

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry it looks like I can only tick one answer, the previous answer was precise to what I was asking but your answer is also correct, I thought I could tick both!